# Please help translate this short Latin phrase left behind by a deceased man

Tags: meaning, sentence-translation

I worked an estate sale a few years ago and the experience has never left me. The man who passed away left this note on a chalk board and I found a photo of it the other day. I have wondered what it says ever since! I took Latin in college, but it was so long ago and I don't have my books anymore. I believe it says something about speaking or praying to God.

> "ora deo sed ab saxis remiga"

Any help?

Comment: [Related](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5143/a-dios-rogando-y-con-el-mazo-dando) question that may have to do with the sense of the phrase

Comment: Similar to "Praise the Lord and pass the ammo" .

Answer (score 19):

**Pray to God but row away from the rocks.**

You are correct in that *ora* means "pray" (it is the singular imperative of *oro*). *Deo* (dative of *Deus*) is the "to God" bit. *Sed* means "but," *ab saxis* (ablative plural) means "away from the rocks," and finally *remiga* is the singular imperative of *remigo* meaning "row."

Now, the meaning of the quote, as I take it, is thus: look to God if you are in trouble, but do not expect a sudden, divine intervention to occur. You have to take matters into your own hands if you have a problem (row away from the rocks). I cannot find if this comes from somewhere specific, so if someone does find that, it would be interesting to hear.

---

**Edit**

The user Jay says this, which is what I was trying to get at in my original answer:

> This seems a pretty routine Christian belief. There's a common saying
>   among Christians today, "Pray as if everything depended on God; work
>   as if everything depended on you." In the Bible, God routinely
>   expected people to do all they could even if he performed a miracle.
>   Like he would promise victory in battle, but the soldiers still had to
>   go out and fight. Even if there was nothing practical a person could
>   do, God often demanded a token effort. Like Naaman had to dunk himself
>   in the Jordan River before God would cure his leprosy. Etc.

Comment: I wonder if there are any classical references for "remigo ab", or if this even makes sense in Latin.

Comment: Thanks very much! What a huge help you've been. I would be very interested to know if it is from somewhere specific – that might shed more meaning on it. Many many thanks.

Comment: Although the adversative _sed_ might have been put there intentionally to twist the sense of the original meaning, I find more likely that the intention was to just go with it. If the deceased man who left the note was a believer, he probably meant that even if God does not need our help, he expects us to do our part while asking Him for help. (See the question I linked for more detail.)

Comment: "remigo ab" +s 'away from' is the primary meaning in my dictionary. Example: Historia Salonitanorum Atque Spalatinorum Pontificum (p.240) 
Thomas (Spalatensis, Archdeacon), 1666;    '...ab insula versus Almisium remigabat.'

Comment: @Rafael Interesting take on it. I added your interpretation to my answer.

Comment: Derived from your answer one could think of another, slightly different meaning:
You can always pray to god for help, but don't bring yourself into dangerous situations foolishly and expect him to help.

Comment: @Jay, SamK, I see two possible nuances that could seem likely in the eyes of a present-day positivist or antitheist, but I think they aren't if the author was a believer or he just wanted to translate a popular saying. I was looking for a way to make this _caveat_. One of these nuances is "yeah, praying is a nice thing, but don't count on God", the other one is similar: "yeah, praying is a nice thing, but if you really want what you are asking for, you have to do whatever it takes, even if it's not what God wants you to do" (which is the kind of bell that _pass the ammo_ rings me.)

Comment: @Rafael An atheist might certainly say, "Well, you go ahead and pray if you want, but as for me, I'm going to row for shore." That isn't the tone I get from this particular quote, but as I don't know anything about the person who said it, it's certainly possible that I'm misreading his intent.

Comment: Well I know he grew up catholic, but was not an active practitioner. I gathered that he was a believer at one time, but those beliefs might have changed based on hardships or experiences. He also was not a man that fit into the traditional mold of a catholic at all based on what I know of his life. I would say if anything he believed in nature. He could be found canoeing in the early morning hours several days a week. I thought that might lend some significance to the rowing away from the rocks part of this.

Answer (score 7):

Many details show that this sentence cannot be ancient (and in fact there is no trace of it in the usual places). While there are no obvious mistakes, it is clear that it is a literal translation from English with no attempt to produce idiomatic Latin. This does not mean that the translator didn’t know enough Latin: the purpose might have been humoristic.

In fact, it is the translation of
[***Call on God but row away from the rocks.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22call+on+god+but+row+away+from+the+rocks%22&oq=%22)

As you can see, it is a rather popular quote whose origin might prove hard to trace. Some sites claim it is an American Indian proverb. I seriously doubt it, because, as other users have explained marvelously, the idea is deeply rooted in Christianity. I don’t think it is of Southern European origin either: on our shores, the one to pray for safety at sea is [*Maria, Stella Maris.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady,_Star_of_the_Sea)

There is one particular point which I’d like to discuss in this context.
In English (and many related languages), the normal way to express motion is to choose a verb which shows the mode of displacement, while the direction is expressed by a complement. In English *you walk down the hill.* In Latin (and in Romance languages) *pedibus a colle descendis,* with a directional verb and a complement of manner. So, when translating *row away from the rocks,* it is not idiomatic to use the very specific verb *remigo,* which is meant for a situation with a very strong focus on rowing. My own translation of the same sentence would be something like

*Precibus Deum invocans remis a rupibus navem averte.*

The OP asked in a comment:

> He canoed all the time and even invented a canoe paddle... so I wonder if he specifically chose that verb *remigo* for this translation given his love of canoeing?

Well, it’s difficult to say. Most probably his love of canoeing influenced his choice of a quote, but no, I don’t think his literal translation was also influenced.