# Latin translation of common adage: God helps those who help themselves

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Is this an accurate Latin translation of "God himself will come to the aid of those who help themselves?": Sese iuvantes Deus ipse adiuvat (or adiuvabit)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5143/a-dios-rogando-y-con-el-mazo-dando) question and the corresponding answers help?

Answer (score 9):

It is a very ancient proverbial topos, widespread in Greece (cfr. Aeschylus, *Pers.* 742 and fr. inc. 395 Radt; Euripides, *IT*, 910-911) and Rome.

In Latin you can consider:

- Varr. *rust.* 1,1,4: *dei facientes adiuvant*
- Hor. *serm.* 1,9,59-60: *nil sine magno / vita labore dedit mortalibus*

The same *topos* underlies the concept expressed by Sallust  *Cat.* 52.59: *non votis neque suppliciis muliebribus auxilia deorum parantur; vigilando, agundo, bene consulendo prospere omnia cedunt*, and in Erasmus' Adagia (3,1,55) we find *industriam adiuvat deus*.

Considering Varro's text, I would suggest “*Ipse Deus sese iuvantes adiuvat*”, but your sentence might be fine too.

Comment: To all those can be added the hundreds of phrases about *fortuna* and *audentes*.

Comment: Of course. I preferred to cite some examples where there is a god who helps those who work for themselves.

Comment: Don't let *Fortuna* hear you talk about her like that!

Comment: Sure, but the topos with Fortuna (Fortes Fortuna adiuvat, cf. eg Ter. Phorm. 203; Cic. fin. 3,4,16; Liv. 8,29,5 and 34,37,4; Plin. ep . 6,16,11) has a different semantic value; also, in  Audentes Fortuna iuvat (Verg. Aen. 10.284), audentes properly designates a temporary state of mind which is just the opposite of fortis

Comment: That was tongue-in-cheek, of course, but I do think the Romans would have been cognizant of the semantic overlap of Fortuna (dea) and fortuna (idea). In some ways, I'd also argue that *audentes* is a closer analogue to the *iuvantes* - in both cases the object of the gods' aid is doing something on their own accord, whereas *fortes* describes what those people simply are. All are temporary, though, since as we all know, *valet ima summis deus/Fortuna*.

Comment: Good to see you posting again after your long hiatus.

Comment: It's a pleasure to see you again here!

Answer (score 6):

Where did you get the Latin from? Did you translate it yourself? Providing more details will always yield a better and more accurate response.

The Latin as you have it is technically correct. *Deus ipse* is in the nominative, *adiuvat* is present tense, *iuvantes* is plural accusative participle, the object of *adiuvat*, and *sese* is an acceptable form of the reflexive, also in the accusative because it's now the object of *iuvantes*. More literally, "God helps the ones helping themselves."

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I translated this version of the common adage "God helps those who help themselves," into Latin, after slightly modifying it for emphasis, because I could not find a literal Latin translation online. I then posted the question to reassure myself that my (German) high school Latin (4 years),which is 1960's vintage and thus very rusty, was still adequate for a simple task like this. Thanks again!